# Pass multiple rows from awk to xargs

Tags: awk, pipe, xargs, top

I want an easy way to monitor the resource usage of processes matching certain keywords.

So I do something like:

```
ps -aux | grep XX | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $2}' | xargs -o -I {} top -p {}
```

(`pgrep` won't work in my case)

This allows me to get the PID of the 2nd row of the `ps` output and pass it to `top`. I can monitor only *one* process in this way.

But suppose there are many lines matching the search term and I want to monitor all of them using `top`.

So the `awk` command will be just `{print $2}` and it'll output multiple rows, each with 1 PID.

**I want to have something like `top -p PID1 -p PID2 ...`**

How do I pass all those PIDs to `top` via `xargs` (or another easy way)?

Comment: Ummm ... with your `FNR==2` you'll only ever output one PID? The 2nd one from the top?

Comment: P.S.: If you find yourself using `awk` after `grep` in a pipe, you're most likely doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, I can change the number passed to `FNR`. So it is a manual process. Why do you say it is a bad idea to have `awk` after `grep`? If the output of `grep` is structured (as in the case of grepping a `ps`), is it still a bad idea? What is a good general alternative?

Comment: Because `awk` does pattern matching just as well as `grep`. Guess efficiency matters less w/ modern hardware. ;)

Comment: @dakini `grep X | awk '{foo}'` = `awk '/X/{foo}'` and `grep X | grep -v Y` = `awk '/X/ && !/Y/`. You never need grep (or sed) when you're using awk and if you ever find yourself piping any combination of grep, sed, and/or awk to/from each other you should probably only be using awk.

Comment: Yeah, `awk` regex isn't something I had used. Mostly used it for simple parsing of tabular data. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: FYI the regexps used in `awk` are just EREs, same as used by `grep -E` and `sed -E`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** this does what you're asking:

```
ps -aux | awk 'BEGIN{printf "top "} /XX/{printf "-p %s ",$2}END{print ""}'|xargs -o -I {} bash -c "{}"
```

Comment: `xargs` and `bash` seem a complicated way to do something like `top $(ps -aux | awk '/XX/{printf "-p %s ",$2}')`

Comment: It is kinda necessary to use `grep` because it can later be further piped to `grep -v` to exclude the `grep` process itself from the `ps` output... Having the PID of the `grep` process in the output won't work.

Comment: @thrig when doing `top $(...)`, when there are multiple PIDs matching the search term, `top` just picks up the last one from the list. Not sure why.

Comment: `ps | grep X'[X]'` will exclude a match on`grep`, and the same regex trick works in `awk`, so `grep` still is redundant